# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in CODE on line 150 Errors parsing CODE

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, syntax

i've bee trying to figure this out forever. I have looked every where and cannot fix this. I'm not that great of a coder so I really don't know what's wrong. I have asked several people and they helped me with other errors and then this came up and they couldn't help. it's been error after error with this, please help. This is wordpress just to help a little bit.

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
/*
Template Name: test
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/titlebar' ); ?>

<div id='page-wrap' class='container'>

        <div id='content' class='sidebar-right twelve columns'>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id='post-<?php the_ID(); ?>' <?php post_class(); ?>>

                        <div class='entry'>

                                <?php the_content(); ?>

                                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                        </div>

                </article>

                <?php if(!$data['check_disablecomments']) { ?>
                        <?php comments_template(); ?>
                <?php } ?>


        </div> <!-- end content -->


        <?php
/*** begin our session ***/

/*** first check that both the username, password and form token have been sent ***/
if(!isset( $_POST['phpro_username'], $_POST['phpro_password'], $_POST['form_token']))
{
    $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
}
/*** check the form token is valid ***/
elseif( $_POST['form_token'] != $_SESSION['form_token'])
{
    $message = 'Invalid form submission';
}
/*** check the username is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['phpro_username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['phpro_username']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Username';
}
/*** check the password is the correct length ***/
elseif (strlen( $_POST['phpro_password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['phpro_password']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Length for Password';
}
/*** check the username has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['phpro_username']) != true)
{
    /*** if there is no match ***/
    $message = 'Username must be alpha numeric';
}
/*** check the password has only alpha numeric characters ***/
elseif (ctype_alnum($_POST['phpro_password']) != true)
{
        /*** if there is no match ***/
        $message = 'Password must be alpha numeric';
}
else
{
    /*** if we are here the data is valid and we can insert it into database ***/
    $phpro_username = filter_var($_POST['phpro_username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $phpro_password = filter_var($_POST['phpro_password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    /*** now we can encrypt the password ***/
    $phpro_password = sha1( $phpro_password );

    /*** connect to database ***/
    /*** mysql hostname ***/
    $mysql_hostname = 'localhost';

    /*** mysql username ***/
    $mysql_username = ‘test_user’;

    /*** mysql password ***/
    $mysql_password = 'test';

    /*** database name ***/
    $mysql_dbname = ‘test;

    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", test, "test");

 /*** $message = a message saying we have connected ***/

        /*** set the error mode to excptions ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        /*** prepare the insert ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO phpro_users (phpro_username, phpro_password ) VALUES (:phpro_username, :phpro_password )');

        /*** bind the parameters ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(':phpro_username', $phpro_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':phpro_password', $phpro_password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        $stmt->execute();

        /*** unset the form token session variable ***/
        unset( $_SESSION['form_token'] );

        /*** if all is done, say thanks ***/


header("Location: aconfirmation);

   catch(Exception $e)
    {
        /*** check if the username already exists ***/
        if( $e->getCode() == 23000)
        {
            $message = 'Username already exists';
        }
        else
        {
            /*** if we are here, something has gone wrong with the database ***/
            $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later';
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Affiliate</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
</html>


</div> <!-- end page-wrap -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Main Issue:**

You do not have an `endwhile` statement for your while loop. Add this to an appropriate place

```
<?php endwhile;?>    // This goes where loop has to end
```

Other issues

**1**

```
header("Location: aconfirmation);
```

is missing a `"`

```
header("Location: aconfirmation");
```

**2**

You don't have a closing `}` for the `try` block

<strike>This then causes the remaining errors Too. But you know what's funny? I didn't have to go through all your code, I just took help from SO syntax highlighter and then noticed what was obviously wrong, You can also use it to your benefit before submitting a question.</strike>

Comment: The funny thing is I do you syntax highlighter. The quotation is not my problem, I accidentally edited it out when editing out my information. The quotation mark is in there, that did not fix the problem. Thanks for the help though. if you know how to fix my current problem please help.

Comment: While we can only answer based on the information provided and hence a mistaken edit can also throw off an answer, so we have to take extra care about replicating our issue correctly when we ask a question. That being said, please see the updated answer and you'll get the answer you are looking for. Cheers

Comment: @hanky-panky I did this and it gave me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in CODE on line 135
Errors parsing CODE, I removed that one and then it went back to the footer error. Any idea?

Comment: Where did you place it? Just after the header call?

Comment: Do you mind explaining where I should put it? I'm still learning php and would appreciate it so I know where to put it for future references, same as with the endwhile statement shown above if you do not mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly brace and a quotation mark

```
    header("Location: aconfirmation"); // <-- HERE
} // <-- HERE
catch(Exception $e)
{
```

Comment: Yes I know, that was by accident when I was in editing the code to edit out my info. That is not my problem, but thanks.